# Rails 3 AJAX: wrong constant name

Tags: ajax, controller, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to do Ajax login with Devise, as explained here: http://jessehowarth.com/2011/04/27/ajax-login-with-devise#comment-5 (see comment from jBeasley).

My controller is attempting to return

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def failure
    render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end
end
```

which results in this error:

```
NameError (wrong constant name ["{\"success\":false,\"errors\":[\"Login failed.\"]}"]Controller):
```

and Firebug showing [500 Internal Server Error].

How can I fix this?  I am running Rails 3.1 and devise 1.4.5.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you do the step recommended by Jeff Poulton in comment #4?  The `:recall` option in 1.4.5 looks to be completely incompatible to older versions.  It now requires you send the controller, whereas in the tutorial you're following he just sends the action (the old way).

In your case, `:recall => :failure` *must* be changed to `:recall => "users/sessions#failure"` in Devise 1.4.5.

This is because of the way the controller for the failure action is determined.  In older versions, it was simply pulled from the params.

```
def recall_controller
  "#{params[:controller]}.camelize}Controller".constantize
end

# called via recall_controller.action(warden_options[:recall]).call(env)
```

In 1.4.5, it expects a string specifying the controller and action, in the style of routes:

```
def recall_app(app)
  controller, action = app.split('#')
  controller_name = ActiveSupport::Inflector.camelize(controller)
  controlller_klass = ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize("#{controller_name}Controller")
  controller_klass.action(action)
end

# called via recall_app(warden_options[:recall]).call(env)
```

It would seem as though your app is actually passing the JSONified hash of options to `recall_app`, which, lacking a '#', isn't being split, and the entire string is concatenated to "Controller" to attempt to ascertain the failure controller's class.

Comment: I was doing :recall => failure.  I changed it to "users/sessions#failure", and now Firebug gets {"success":false,"errors":["Login failed."]} as a response.  Great, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation. I was still confused because I knew my original version *was* calling def failure even if the route was misspecified.  So my question was 'why would my version result in an error while the correct route wouldn't, given that both call def failure anyway?'.  Your explanation about the split makes sense -- I'll try to follow the source code myself and hopefully learn some rails in the process... Thanks again!

Comment: hah I was just looking at this trying to puzzle out why the actual JSON was making it into the method, and noticed your first comment.  Sure the failure method was called, because you're actually calling it inline.  If you note the tutorial he's passing the symbol `:failure`, referring to the recall method to call later.  Yours is calling failure inline, storing the JSON as `warden[:recall]` and eventually sending it straight to `recall_app`.  So you can see how that weird constantize call came to happen.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the return in

```
def failure
    return render:json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
end
```

Does that make a difference?

Comment: No difference, that return is optional.